# When do different binomial coefficients coincide?

Tags: arithmetic, binomial-coefficients, diophantine-equations

A tongue-in-cheek recent [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2294472/is-there-an-elegant-bijective-proof-of-binom155-binom146#2294630) here inspired me another, less ambiguous question : say that a binom coefficient $\binom{x}{y}$ (where $x$ and $y$ are positive integers) is nontrivial-and-normalized if $1<y \leq \frac{x}{2}$. The question then goes, find all "coincidences" of the form $\binom{x}{y}=\binom{x'}{y'}$ where both $\binom{x}{y}$ and $\binom{x'}{y'}$ are nontrivial-and-normalized, and of course $(x,y)\neq (x',y')$. If this is too hard, does this equation have finitely or infinitely many solutions ?

My thoughts : with a computer, I found that the only coincidences with $\max(x,x')\leq 100$ are

$$
\begin{array}{c}
120=\binom{16}{2}=\binom{10}{3},
210=\binom{10}{4}=\binom{21}{2}, \\
1540=\binom{22}{3}=\binom{56}{2},
3003=\binom{14}{6}=\binom{15}{5}=\binom{78}{2}.
\end{array}
$$

**Update 05/26/2017:** Judging from all the references given in the comments, the first question ("find all the coincidences") is an open problem, and the second question has an affirmative answer : there is indeed an infinite number of solution pairs. See the Wikipedia link on Singmaster's conjecture, quoted in the comments.

Comment: Then, you haven't understood the answer to that question. The diophantine equation in that special case is still manageable, but in general, there's little hope. You've heard that the general problem of diophantine equations is undecidable, haven't you? And that's just the existence of solutions, let alone their number.

Comment: @ProfessorVector what did I not understand, in which answer ?

Comment: It may have been a comment, too, does that really matter?

Comment: if what you say doesn't matter, don't speak ... :-)

Comment: I think https://arxiv.org/abs/1411.4111 has a lot to say about this question. An earlier paper is http://www.mathstat.dal.ca/FQ/Scanned/13-4/singmaster.pdf

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singmaster%27s_conjecture (but this doesn't know about the first paper I cite above).

Comment: There's also a paper of de Weger in J Number Theory. An earlier version of that paper is available at https://repub.eur.nl/pub/1356

Comment: As background, this problem is Exercise 47 on page 93 of "Advanced Combinatorics" by Comtet.  The problem is starred, indicating a more difficult exercise, and the solution is not in the book.

Comment: Had a chance to look at those references, Ewan?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes, I have looked at all the online ones. My initial question is basically an open problem today and there is little to add to those references. I updated my OP a little bit.

Comment: 6 C 2 should be 16 C 2.

Comment: @RosieF Corrected, thanks.